# Как посчитать количество вхождений числа "100" в таблице "table_" в БД "bazabanyh" в поле "good"?

Tags: php, mysql

Как посчитать количество вхождений числа "100" в таблице "table_" в БД "bazabanyh" в поле "good"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(*) from table_ where good = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Ввиду не достаточно точной формулировки вопроса, может быть такой вариант

```
SELECT
  SUM(
    LENGTH(
      TRIM(
        CAST( good AS VARCHAR(255) )
      )
    ) -
    LENGTH(
      REPLACE(
        TRIM(
          CAST( good AS VARCHAR(255) )
        ),
        '100',
        ''
      )
    )
  ) / 3
FROM
  table_
```

Если падает с ошибкой - замените "`CAST( good AS VARCHAR(255) )`" на "`good`"

Comment: че за пляски с бубном?) может объяснишь еще.. зачем на 3 делить? зачем делать адское отнимание?

Comment: Мой вариант считает **сколько раз в табличном поле** встречается подстрока '100'.

Твой вариант считает **в скольки строках таблицы** встречается подстрока '100'.

Разные задачи решаем.

Comment: разобрался ) прикольный метод )

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой запрос

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_ WHERE good LIKE '% 100 %'
```

Если поля good должно быть в точности равному 100, то как подсказал [[@Gorets](/users/3608/gorets)](/users/3608/gorets)